# Book about a boy born on spaceship who befriends some alien bugs when they get to the destination planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

My apologies but details are a little fuzzy, I read it when I was in fourth or fifth grade and I'm 21 now, so around 2007 to 2009. The cover had an illustration of the boy.

From what I remember, it was about this boy whose parents were scientists and were on a spaceship on its way to a different planet. The boy was born and raised in the space ship and when they finally landed he somehow met a race of bug-like aliens. He befriended them and had to do his best keeping them a secret from the adults he grew up surrounded by.

Comment: The first thing I thought of was _[Serpent's Reach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent's_Reach)_ by CJ Cherryh, but not enough things match.

Comment: Sounds like "Space Mowgli", by Boris and Arkady Strugatsky, see the plot here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Mowgli

Comment: This also reminds me a bit of "Big Sword" by Paul Ash (Pauline Ashwell/Whitby) http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55650

Answer (score 5):

As @m-a-golding commented, this seems to match "Big Sword" by Pauline Ashwell aka Pauline Whitby, published in the October 1958 of Astounding under the name Paul Ash. It can be read [here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v62n02_1958-10_EXciter-LennyS/page/n62/mode/2up) on the Internet Archive.

The story alternates between viewpoints of the grasshopper-like aliens and the humans.  The aliens have been separated for many generations from another population of similar aliens by a geologic rift, and they have a tradition of attempting to cross the rift. The boy makes telepathic contact with the bugs and tries to hide it from the adults around him because they'll think he's nuts -- his psych profile being unstable is mentioned early in the story.  The boy finally helps the aliens reach their kin and is vindicated.